# Copying enum property from one class to another

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes with exact type properties but with different property names. So I want to copy every property to corresponding property which resides in different class.

For example

```
public class ClassOne
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Code {get; set;}
   public UserMode Mode {get; set;}
   public enum UserMode {A=1, B=2, C=3};
}

public class ClassTwo
{
   public string MyName {get; set;}
   public string MyCode {get; set;}
   public MyUserMode Mode {get; set;}
   public enum MyUserMode MyMode {AA=1, BB=2, CC=3};
}
```

Since this only cross on my mind I created Helper method which converts ClassOne To ClassTwo taking every member and copy it's values like

```
public static ClassTwo(ClassOne one)
{
  var two = new ClassTwo()
  {
    MyName = one.Name,
    MyCode = one.Code,
    // how to copy enum value ??
  };
}
```

Question is: How can I copy enums like I did above with Name and Code?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: The above code will not compile.. Name, Code, MyName, MyCode doesn't specify any datatype.

Comment: it still won't compile, because `Name` and `Code` isn't a part of `ClassTwo`. Did you mean `MyName = Name;` and `MyCode = Code`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just cast it to an `int` and then to the new enum:

```
public static ClassTwo(ClassOne one)
{
  var two = new ClassTwo()
  {
    Name = one.Name,
    Code = one.Code,
    Mode = (ClassTwo.MyUserMode)((int)one.Mode);
  };
}
```

This is assuming that both enums have the **exact** same `int` values.

A safer way to do this would be using [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx):

```
public static ClassTwo(ClassOne one)
{
  var mode = (ClassTwo.MyUserMode)((int)one.Mode);
  if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ClassTwo.MyUserMode), mode)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot map enums.");
  var two = new ClassTwo()
  {
    Name = one.Name,
    Code = one.Code,
    Mode = mode
  };
}
```

Comment: Throw in some [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) checking just to be sure and that should be it.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `int` first; you can just do: `var mode = (ClassTwo.MyUserMode)one.Mode;`

Answer (score 2):

You can cast value to int

```
MyMode = (MyUserMode)((int)one.UserMode)
```